# Question about finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup\{ | f-f_n | : x \in \mathbb{R}\} $

Tags: real-analysis

Say that $f_n$ is a sequence of functions and $f$ is its limit function.
My book shows a way to find
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup\{ | f-f_n | : x \in \mathbb{R}\} $
by differentiating and solving for $0$, just as when trying to find the local extremum of a function.

There’s only one example of this in my book, and they differentiate $f-f_n$ without the absolute value signs. I think it might just be because the function is already positive, but I want to make sure:
If trying this approach on a function that isn’t always positive, should I differentiate $f-f_n$ or $|f-f_n|$?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be something missing in your problem formulation.  There isn't enough information to "find" local extrema of $f-f_n$ or even to show a derivative exists.  Possibly you've overlooked what your book means by $f$ being the limit of the sequence $f_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_n-f|$ and $f_n,f$ are explicitly given, one way to do it is to really find the value of $\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_n-f|$ for a fixed $n$. The classical way to do that is to study $f_n-f$: compute derivatives and find the monotonicity intervals. I guess that's what your book shows.

If you want to find $\sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}}|f_n-f|$ with calculus you always differentiate and study $f_n-f$ for two reasons:

- the absolute value is not differentiable so $|f_n-f|$ may have points where the function is not derivable (example $|x^2-3x+2|$).
- if you study $f_n-f$ and find the maximum and minimum values you can easily deduce the maximal value of $|f_n-f|$

Comment: Thank you very much, that cleared it up for me!